# How to : on name select get the id of that particular selected record

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am displaying records from Database in Selectbox (select2). Like this

```
<select  name="comic_publisher" id="publishers">
            @foreach($group as $team)
                <option value="{{$team->comic_group_name}}">{{$team->comic_group_name}}</option>
            @endforeach
      </select>
```

Here I have to do such functionality like if I select name from selectbox then selected record's id means(team->id) automatically save in a hidden field. so I can save that into table. I am stuck and don't know how to do that with laravel.

and Here is the Controller function:-

```
 public function create()
    {

           $group = Group::all(['comic_group_name']);
           return View('comic.create', compact('group',$group));
    }
```

Any help from experts.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify your question... This is really unclear...

Comment: Assume if I select the comic name "marvel" from selectbox then can i able to get that selected record's id automatically means "marvel's id".

Comment: That select is in a form? When you post that form the value of the selected item will be returned in the comic_publisher field... thus you set the value to the ID you want... would value="{{$team->id}}" work? When you post a questions it is good to give a little more context... We have no idea what the Group model has ... what the post controller does...

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it well just pass model id to option value, like this:

```
<option value="{{ $team->id }}">
    {{$team->comic_group_name}}
</option>
```